# Access S3 from AWS EC2 from AWS SDK without Access Id and secret Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

How can **AWS-SDK** that runs from **AWS-EC2** instance access **AWS-S3** bucket?

1. The **AWS-EC2** policy is set such that it can access the **S3
       bucket** without accessId and secret key.
2. **Aws-cli** tool was able to access the **S3 bucket** from EC2 instance without the need of any *accessId and secret key*.
3. If **aws-cli** tool was able to access the S3 without *accessId and secret* key, the AWS-SDK must also have a way to do it while it runs
       from EC2 instance.

How can this be done?

Comment: Create an IAM instance profile and associate it with EC2 instance.

Comment: Creating an IAM profile also requires accessId and secret key to be configured to access S3 bucket from AWS-SDK.

Comment: You do not need access id and key if you have IAM Profile. Simply run the command `aws s3 copy ...`

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. Using aws-cli tool, I can execute commands like "aws s3 copy..." or whatever. But what I need is, to do the same thing using AWS-SDK. I want to access the S3 bucket using a JAVA program, or python program. The AWS-SDK for java requires Secret key and access ID. but how do i access it without accessid and secret key via a program?

Comment: Any program that uses an AWS SDK will automatically find credentials if you have assigned an IAM role to the EC2 instance. There is no need to provide an Access Key + Secret Key. (By the way, the AWS CLI is simply a Python program, which obtains credentials via the AWS SDK for Python.)

Answer (score 1):

Create your client using [AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3ClientBuilder.html#defaultClient--). This uses [DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html) as mentioned in the link.

> AWS credentials provider chain that looks for credentials in this
>   order:
>
> - Environment Variables - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY    (RECOMMENDED since they are recognized by all the AWS SDKs and CLI
>     except for .NET), or AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_KEY (only
>     recognized by Java SDK)
> - Java System Properties - aws.accessKeyId and    aws.secretKey
> - Credential profiles file at the default location    (~/.aws/credentials) shared by all AWS SDKs and the AWS CLI
> - Credentials delivered through the Amazon EC2 container service if    AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI" environment variable is set
>     and security manager has permission to access the variable,
> - Instance profile credentials delivered through the Amazon EC2 metadata service